# Getting all past events in web3JS

Tags: web3js, events, react

I have seen similar questions here, but the answers didn't help so far.

I have a JS function in a React component that should parse all the past events of the contract. The function is invoked in `componentWillMount()`, and my intention is to get all the event results as objects, store them in the state and then render.

The function:

```
getAllEvents() {
    const contract = require("truffle-contract");
    const contract= contract(ContractOne);
    contract.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider);

    var contractInstance;

    this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
      contract.deployed().then(instance => {
        contractInstance = instance;

        var events = contractInstance.EventResults({
          fromBlock: 0,
          toBlock: "latest"
        });
        events.watch(
          function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("error!");
            } else {
              this.setState(prevState => ({
                eventData: [...prevState.eventData, result.args]
              }));
            }
          }.bind(this)
        );
      });
    });
  }
```

However, I get only the very last event object rendered with this function, instead having shown quite a bunch. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be of help but if you use this endpoint:

```
https://web3api.io/api/v1/addresses/<address>/logs
```

Api keys are free and easy to obtain. You can get all past events of any address. In this case it would the contract address.

Example:

```js
const axios = require('axios')

let headers = {
    'x-api-key': 'UAK000000000000000000000000demo0001'
}
let url = 'https://web3api.io/api/v1/addresses/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d/logs'
let getCryptokittiesEvents = () => {
    axios.get(url, {'headers': headers})
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.payload.records)
    })
}
```

There are also options to add filters to the query. You can find more details [here](https://docs.amberdata.io/v1.0/reference#get-address-logs).

Please let me know if that is helpful at all!

Comment: It is helpful, but not quite what I was looking for!